# How to underline a menu item when hover over it?

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I'm building the following website with WordPress right now: https://shaveiceberlin.de

When I hover over a menu item, how can I get a underline effect, like on this website: https://snocks.com ?

My current css code:

```
#site-header.center-header #site-navigation-wrap .middle-site-logo:hover img {
-moz-opacity: 1;
-webkit-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks lovely team for helping me!
Kind regards,
Jonas

Comment: None of those  browsers has needed those vendor prefixes for decades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pseudo selector coupled with animating the `transform` property. The `transform-origin` is important because it dictates form where the animation is coming from and returns to. It defaults to `center` which is why I'm overriding it to `left`.

```css
.menu a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.menu a::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #ff7000;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.menu a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Plain link</a>

<nav class="menu">
  <a href="#">Underline on hover or focus</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! I changed your code a bit, but now I really like the result. But now the underlining effect is at buttons, the logo and pictures as well now. I just need it at the menu. Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Jonmue I adjusted the `HTML` and `CSS` to show how you would isolate the styles to anchors within a specific `class`.

Comment: thanks Andy! I know hot to add css to Wordpress, but I have no idea how to add or adjust html in Wordpress. I already searched the internet, but couldn't find a solution that works. Can you help me one last time?

Comment: @Jonmue I'd love to help but you should open a new question .